# Is it OK to use 1 condition variable associated with 2 mutex (separately)

Tags: c++, mutex, condition-variable

I would like to ask whether it is OK to use 1 condition variable associated with 2 mutex, for 2 kind of data update.

Basically, I have thread1 and thread2.  Thread1 could wait for 2 kinds of data update, so it got 2 mutex, one for each.  (I know I could use one mutex for all these data, but this is not the point of this question, right?)  And I certainly does not want it be waiting on data1 while data2 is already available, so it only got 1 condition variable.  And thread2 would provide both data1 and data2.  The problem is that in thread2, I don't know whether thread1 is now waiting for data1 or data2 or not waiting at all.

Pseudo code would look like below:

```
global data:
    cond_var
    mutex1
    data1
    mutex2
    data2

thread1:
    while true
        lock1.lock(mutex1)
        if data1 is not available
        cond_var.wait(lock1)
        if data1 is available
            process data1
        lock1.unlock()

        lock2.lock(mutex2)
        if data2 is not available
            cond_var.wait(lock2)
        if data2 is available
            process data2
        lock2.unlock()

thread2:
    func1:
        lock1.lock(mutex1)
        update data1
        cond_var.notify_all()
        lock1.unlock()

    func2:
        lock2.lock(mutex2)
        update data2
        cond_var.notify_all()
        lock2.unlock()
```

Outside world will call func1 or func2 to update the data.
When func1 or func2 is called, it will signal cond_var, whether it is in lock1 or lock2.  The wait of cond_var is not surrounded by while, so if cond_var is waked on lock1 but data2 is available, thread1 will go on to process data2.

The actual implementation is via boost::thread, and since the platform for my test is Linux, boost::thread should be implemented via pthread.

In almost all tutorial and documents I read about condition variable, it is associated with only 1 mutex.  So I am curious to know whether the above program is OK to use, or is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: I Want to say no.Because,you use one cond_var,so you can't distinguish the signal source is "update data1" or "update data2".

Comment: No I cannot.  But I only want it to wake thread1 so it could continue.  Thread1 will check by itself if data1 or data2 is updated.  So thread1 does know which is updated.

I know the question is kind of corner case, since I probably not able to increase to 3 mutex in this program.
Well, if I break thread1 to 2 separated thread I could use 3 mutex for 3 kinds of data...

Comment: I strongly advise against even *trying* to do this. The the ability to enter wait, etc, is all predicated on the atomicity of the condition variable and the mutex. OT, easily my *favorite* text on POSIX threads (with an **outstanding** section on condition variables) is [Programming with POSIX Threads](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-POSIX-Threads-David-Butenhof/dp/0201633922). It is worth the read if you're interested in having a text on your desk.

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig for the recommended book.  In fact I just read the section of condition variable (https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) before I post the question.  I actually is hoping a NO.  I just want to know "why not" "what disaster will happen if you do this", not just that "it is not the standard way of doing things"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is OK.

Boost.Thread implements the C++11 thread library (it had some differences until v1.50 but is now very close) and that thread library is conceptually close to the Pthread model, but using a different API, so we can look at those specs for the answer.

The rule in the C++11 standard is:

> *Requires:* `lock.owns_lock()` is `true` and `lock.mutex()` is locked by the calling thread, and either
>    — no other thread is waiting on this `condition_variable` object or
>    — `lock.mutex()` returns the same value for each of the `lock` arguments supplied by all concurrently waiting (`via wait`, `wait_for`, or `wait_until`) threads.

In your case the mutex is correctly locked and there is only ever one thread waiting on the condvar, so the condition is met.

The rule in POSIX is equivalent, but worded differently:

> The  effect  of using more than one mutex for concurrent `pthread_cond_timedwait()` or `pthread_cond_wait()` operations on the same condition variable is undefined; that is, a condition variable becomes bound to a unique mutex when a thread waits on the  condition  variable,  and  this  (dynamic) binding shall end when the wait returns.

Again, you have no concurrent wait operations.

In general it's OK to use a condvar with different mutexes as long as you never wait using different mutexes *at the same time*.  When waiting on a condvar you associate it with a mutex and a predicate (the "condition") so as POSIX describes, the condvar and mutex are "bound" together and any a condvar must not be bound to more than one mutex at a time.  The reason is that when a condvar wakes up from a wait it must reacquire the mutex it is associated with, if different threads have used it with different mutexes it might re-lock the wrong mutex in the wrong thread, causing chaos. A thread would wake up thinking it has re-locked the mutex it waited with, but it's actually got a lock on a different mutex, maybe one it doesn't have any reference to and so can never unlock. Deadlock and/or undefined behaviour and lions and tigers and bears, oh my.

In your case there are no concurrent waits, so no problem. If you had more than one thread waiting you would need to ensure that the same mutex is used by both threads for any given wait ... which would be difficult as you'd need some additional synchronisation, so it would be simpler to just use two condvars.

Comment: Thanks, very detailed explanation.  So I would be doomed if I break thread1 to 2 threads, and waiting on different mutex at same time with same condition variable.

Comment: Utterly doomed. Your soul would be ripped to shreds and your printer would catch fire! :)  But seriously,  yes, that is undefined behaviour. Your current code is OK, but only because waiting with one mutex _happens before_ waiting with the other mutex, so they never happen concurrently.